# Combining List and dictionary in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a list with a dictionary in it with a list in it like this:

```
a = [{'name': ['item1', 'item2']}]
```

And I need to get that result like this:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'item1',
        'name': 'item2'
    }
]
```

Comment: Keys are unique in a dict . You can not have same key twice

Comment: Your output syntax is incorrect, so not clear what you're trying to create i.e. syntax error `closing parenthesis ']' does not match opening parenthesis '{'`

Answer (score 0):

So for your problem, First your idea is wrong as in a dictionary in python you cannot have same key more than ones as you reference the data with the keys and if duplicate exists then there will be problem.

So the solution could be:

```
[
    {
        'name0': 'item1',
        'name2': 'item2'
    }
]
```

For this you have to iterate through all the elements in the innermost list and create a new dictionary within a list as expected in the desired result and then add elements one by one in the inner dictionary with keys like name1, name2, ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your requirement, I would suggest you to go through the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> It is best to think of a dictionary as a set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

So, as of your desired output of a dictionary with 2 same keys is not possible.

But you may try something like this

```py
a=[{'name': ['item1', 'item2']}]

result_list=[]

for item in a[0]['name']:
    result_list.append({'name':item})

print(result_list)
```

Output

```py
[{'name': 'item1'}, {'name': 'item2'}]
```

This appears to be something similar to your requirement. You can use list index to access the individual dictionaries.